# stop google sheets creating new row when new data is entered in the form

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms, formulas

I have got a Google Spreadsheet that is using a lookup function to lookup name from another sheet according to their ID number but when the ID is entered using the submit form it creates a new row each time and therefore nothing is looked up from the other form.

This is my lookup function currently

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,'Student Details'!A:D,2,FALSE)
```

But I have also tried following other examples and put in:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(C3,'Student Details'!A:D,2,FALSE))
```

None of these formulas are working for me could someone please advice me where i am going wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you want to find the **last** record for that ID or that you want to change the behavior of your google form? The former might include Excel functions; the latter most certainly does not.

Comment: I have got ID, first name, second name and email in one sheet. In the other sheet I have got the ID come from the form submission or the android app I have connected it to. According to the ID entered I would like to lookup the first name, second name and email from the first form associated with the ID.

Comment: The only way to stop Google Sheets creating a new row when new data is entered in the form is to disconnect the Google Form from the spreadsheet. The alternative is to change your formulas but it's not clear in which sheets are the formulas and the form submissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a range in your arrayformula. E.g: in row 2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C2:C), VLOOKUP(C2:C,'Student Details'!A:D,2,FALSE),))
```

make sure the column where you want to use this formula is empty (no data or formula) from row two onwards.